# Multiple Aliases in an SQL Query

Tags: mysql, alias

Would it be possible to give a table in MySQL query multiple aliases?

If so how would I do this?

Comment: Hi, can you help me understand why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you are using the table multiple times in different clauses and/or sub-queries like

```
SELECT SeniorManager = sm.displayName, Manager = m.displayName, Worker = w.displayName
FROM   people AS w
LEFT OUTER JOIN people AS  m ON  m.id = w.bossID
LEFT OUTER JOIN people AS sm ON sm.id = m.bossID
```

But you can *not* give the same use of a table more than one alias - the following for instance is invalid syntax:

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name FROM people AS a1 AND a2
```

Also, you can not (in most DBMSs) use a table by both its real name and alias, so the following is invalid too:

```
SELECT people.name, a1.name FROM people AS a1
```

If ause of an object is given an alias you must refer to that instance by that alias even if the real name is unambiguous within the query.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

For example: for a table such as this:

```
create table staff
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100),
    supervisorId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (SupervisorId) REFERENCES staff(id)
)
```

You can query it like so :

```
select a.name as EmployeeName, b.name as SupervisorName
from staff a,
 staff b
where 
 a.supervisorId = b.id
```

or

```
select a.name as EmployeeName, b.name as SupervisorName
from 
 staff a
 inner join staff b on a.supervisorId = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` To do this, example

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM user AS u1
INNER JOIN user u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
```

But note that will be worse performing than only "one alias"

```
mysql   > DESC select count(*)
          FROM user AS u1
+------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+
|   id | select_type   | table   |   partitions | type   |   possible_keys | key           |   key_len |    ref |   rows |   filtered | Extra       |
|------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+-------------|
|    1 | SIMPLE        | u1      |       <null> | index  |          <null> | client_id_idx |         4 | <null> |   5625 |        100 | Using index |
+------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------+--------+------------+-------------+

mysql   > DESC select count(*)
          FROM user AS u1
          INNER JOIN user u2 ON u1.user_id = u2.user_id
+------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------+-------------+
|   id | select_type   | table   |   partitions | type   | possible_keys   | key           |   key_len | ref                |   rows |   filtered | Extra       |
|------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------+-------------|
|    1 | SIMPLE        | u1      |       <null> | index  | PRIMARY         | client_id_idx |         4 | <null>             |   5625 |        100 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE        | u2      |       <null> | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY       |         4 | gr_cg35.u1.user_id |      1 |        100 | Using index |
+------+---------------+---------+--------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+--------+------------+-------------+
```